# State of canon for Star Wars: Masters of Teräs Käsi

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, video-games, canon

*[Star Wars: Masters of Teräs Käsi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Masters_of_Ter%C3%A4s_K%C3%A4si)* was a 1997 Playstation fighting game featuring several characters from *Star Wars* and was noted to be set between the first and second films. In general, *Star Wars* kept a tight grip on its canon, and events from the various books and games could be considered canonical. Now one might expect that a fighting game's plot might be brushed aside, but it seems the primary antagonist, [Arden Lyn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Arden_Lyn), appeared in other books and games.

Was this game considered to be within the Legends canon? Is it still considered canonical where not contradicted by more recent releases?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it is simply treated as a 'Legends' property along with **all** of the other games published pre 2014

Comment: VTC as unclear - not sure why this would be considered (or rather, why it would even be asked) to be any more canon than anything else pre-Disney, so I don't understand the question tbh

Comment: Not even going to mention that Teras kasi style is now canon,and mentioned in Solo?

Comment: @CBredlow: Weirdly enough, I completely forgot that got mentioned again.